# Jquery radio button with onclick

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, radio-button

I have a radio_button_tag in the following way:

```
 <%= radio_button_tag "content[id]", content.id%><%= content.title %>
```

and have a text_field in the following way:

```
<%= f.text_field :title %>
```

When i click on the radio button, the title of the radio button should populate in the text_field above. I am trying to use jQuery for this.

Comment: It might help if you posted the generated HTML too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's add a title attribute to your radio buttons:

```
<%= radio_button_tag "content[id]", content.id, {}, {:title => content.title} %><%= content.title %>
```

The foregoing should output some HTML which looks like this:

```
<input id="content_id_<content.id>" type="radio" value="<content.id>" title="<content.title>" name="content[id]" />
```

Second, here's the jQuery code:

```
jQuery(function(){
    // For each radio button whose name is 'content[id]':
    jQuery("input[type='radio'][name='content[id]']").each(function(index, button){
        // Give the button a certain click behaviour:
        jQuery(button).click(function(){
            // Set the value of 'title' textfield to the radio's title
            jQuery("#title").val(this.title);
        });
    });
});
```

This anonymous function will execute when the document is done loading. It attaches click behaviour to your buttons, so you don't need an `onclick` attribute.

(This will only add click behaviour to the radio button itself. If you want to add a `<label>` element to each radio button and give it the same behaviour, you'll have to add a bit to the foregoing jQuery code.)

Comment: Where should I put the JS code? In a **<script>** tag after the rest of the html view code or in the controller **coffee file** generated by the scaffold?

Comment: @AlexVentura : I haven't used coffeescript in years, so if you mean to copy-and-paste raw javascript into a coffeescript file, I can't say whether that will be processed correctly. However, you can put the code into a script tag or into a source file. It shouldn't need to be at the end of the html because the `jQuery` function call should not invoke the anonymous function inside of it until after the page has finished loading.

Comment: Alright, actually when you generate an scaffold for a resource it generates a coffee script file but also you can change it to a js file. What I want to know if does it looks pretty nasty to show **<script>** tags between different blocks of HTML in rails views or maybe partials? What do you think?

Comment: @AlexVentura : I agree that I don't like script tags outside of the `<head>`. I would put this code into an external script file and include it in the `<head>`.

Comment: Well I'm going to do something like you said, thanks for your tips!

Answer (score 0):

Unsure about ruby but in .net i would put a class name on the radio, label and text box.  then i can use this;

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".radioClassName").click(function(){

    $(".TextBoxClassName").val($(".radioLabelClassName").text());

  });

});
```

Your html might look like this;

```
<input type=radio class="radioClassName"><label class="radioLabelClassName">my text"</label>

<input type="text" class="TextBoxClassName">
```

Not sure this will work but jQuery is jQuery i think

Answer (score 0):

Assuming html as

```
 <form>
<input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
<input type="radio" id="sex" name="sex" value="female" /> Female

    <input type="text" name="des" id="des" />
</form>
```

Javascript will be

```
$("#des").val($("#sex").val());
$("#sex").change(function(){
    alert($("#sex").val());     
   $("#des").val($("#sex").val());
});
Demo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Wr8dJ/23/

Comment: vivek,i am getting the content.title from the database where as the content.id is the primary_key value of the content table. Here when i click on the radio button, The value of content.title should be specific to the content.id value. So, if i click on the radio button, the value content.title should be displayed in the textbox.

Comment: I am new to this site, i dont know formatting..   <% for content in Content.find(:all, :order  => "created_at desc", :limit => 2) %>

      <%= radio_button_tag "content[id]", content.id%><%= content.title %>

  <% end %>
<br/>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>